# How to configure to send mail via Mailgun in Ghost CMS?

Tags: json, api, mailgun, ghost-blog

> error: Failed to send email. Reason: Invalid login - 535 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password.

I am using the following settings in the `config.production.js` file:

```
  "mail": {
    "from": " 'xyz' xyz.xyz.com",
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "options": {
      "service": "Mailgun",
      "host": "smtp.eu.mailgun.org",
      "port": 465,
      "secureConnection": true,
      "auth": {
        "user": "myuser@mydomain.ghostzones.ml",
        "pass": "passcode"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your Mailgun panel and reset the password for the new SMTP user created.

[image: Ghost CMS Mailgun SMTP]

Then you can set in your file like that:

```
"mail": {
      "from": "'Mageflix' <postmaster@mail.mageflix.com>",
      "transport": "SMTP",
      "options": {
        "service": "Mailgun",
        "host": "smtp.mailgun.org",
        "port": 465,
        "secureConnection": true,
        "auth": {
          "user": "postmaster@mail.mageflix.com",
          "pass": "4d595189e2b37b5c140c6979a9d8627d-46ac6b00-8a10f98c2b"
        }
      }
    },
```